# Aurelia EventAggregator not subscribing

Tags: aurelia

I have a parent-child component architecture in my Aurelia app. `Panel` is a Parent component View-model, inside which there is a `Tool` component.

I have a pagination UI on `Panel`, clicking on which the `Tool` should update. The problem is, the variable which keep track of which page number was clicked, `pageNumber` is only available in `panel.ts` and not available in `tool.ts`. So basically, this is an issue of communicating between two ViewModels.

To solve this issue, I am using Aurelia's `EventAggregator` by following [this](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/working-with-the-aurelia-event-aggregator/) excellent tutorial. Here is what I have written till now:

**panel.html**

```
<a class="page-link" click.delegate="pageClick(1)"> 1 </a>
```

**panel.ts**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class Panel {

eventAggregator: EventAggregator;

constructor(eventAggregator) {
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
}

pageClick(pageNumber) {
    var pageInfo = {
        pageNumber: pageNumber
    }
    this.eventAggregator.publish("pageClicked", pageInfo);
}
```

**tool.ts**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class Tool {

eventAggregator: EventAggregator;

constructor(eventAggregator) {
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
}

pageClicked() {
    this.eventAggregator.subscribe("pageClicked",
        pageInfo => {
            console.log(`${pageInfo.pageNumber} was clicked`);
        });
}
```

This works fine until the event is fired. I tried debugging and saw that `eventAggregator` fired the `pageClicked` event. But the breakpoint on `subscribe` was never hit. Somehow the `subscribe` method is not triggered. What am I missing here?

My initial thought is that `EventAggregator` instance is different, but I am not sure if it needs to be same. Any help is appreciated. Also, if you know some other better way to achieve `intercomponent communication` please let me know how. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the subscription in a function that will be called. Maybe add an `attached` callback and set up the subscription there. Make sure to dispose the subscription, probably in a `detached` callback. I'm on mobile right now, but if you need a code example, let me know, and I'll add one when I get home.

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally forgot that `pageClicked()` was never called and `subscription` was not set at all.

Comment: No problem. Happens to everyone.

Comment: By the way, is `EventAggregator` the preferred way to achieve what I am trying to do here? or is there another way to communicate between different components?

Comment: Based on the info I have, yes. You might also look at custom events.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you.

Comment: if the vm is a route, i set up `subscribe` in attached and `dispose` in detached. otherwise, i set up `subscribe` in `constructor`.